# Logging in AppInsights using PowerShell in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, appinsights

I am trying log to feed logs from Azure Functions to AppInsight somethings similar to:

```
 log.LogInformation($"C# function processed: {myQueueItem}");
```

This actually provides me with a customdimension property in AppInsights. Is there a way to do similar thing using PowerShell?

Is there a simpler way to log Azure Function data to AppInsights?

Answer (score 0):

The logging available for PowerShell functions is using the various streams already available from PowerShell. Most output is logged as `INFORMATION` unless you specifically use warning or error streams.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#logging

Alternatively you could implement something yourself using something like this gist: https://gist.github.com/taddison/d49bd8c6f7fc1d45aa8e7b0906c180ae

Which will allow you to export custom metrics as an object.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#logging I did based on this url and everything logs as INFORMATION. But how can I query them in app insights?